# AdBlock + ajax Не видит элемент

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

На сайте с помощью

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='../js/jquery.min.1.6.4.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='../js/ajax.js'></script>
<div id="blockajax"></div>
```

Выводится блок В ajax.js прописан код :

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $("#blockajax").load("../reklam/reklama.php");
  })
})(jQuery)
```

Но это не реклама а то чтобы выводит на всех страницах одинаковый элемент картинку или текст.

AdBlock все это дело блокирует ! Подскажите как сделать чтобы работал этот код и AdBlock не блокировал его !?

Comment: если это не реклама, то почему он называется `reklama` ? :)

Comment: а вы можете предоставить содержимое файла reklama.php?

Comment: может быть стоит переименовать *"../reklam/reklama.php"* ?

Comment: Весь код выложен верху ! Код реклама php это страница на которой есть кнопочки и прочее Обычная страница Которая подгружается на другие страницы моего сайта Чтобы не дублировать на каждой  а работать с одной !

Comment: Да убрал все надписи reclam и переименовал картинки. Вообщем убрал названия связанные с рекламой, баннер  и так далее ! Спасибо  LANSELOT ! С новым Годом Всех !

Answer (score 1):

Тема старая, но всё же подниму
Если AdBlock или ему подобные блокирует что либо на сайте:

1. открываем панель разработчика в  браузере `F12`
2. в открывшемся блоке выбираем таб с `AdBlock`
3. перезагружаем страницу
4. в появившейся таблице видим почему AdBlock заблокировал данный
   элемент

[image: Фильтры AdBlock]

Comment: Не все так просто, он теперь пачками блокирует, запутывает так что разберешься через сутки, а через 5 суток он новую фигню выкинет ))))) Их там человек 300 сидит только что и делают как просматривают каждый сайт и отдельно вносят, ну не говорю конечно о таких как Яндекс или Google тут шаблон